# Download offline map for current country heremap sdk

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using here-map SDK for map purpose in my application, I have to download an offline map in my device. In which I would like to add a suggestion for the user to download his current country.

From the documentation, a map is downloaded based on the country/places id. My doubt is how to get our country's ID.

I'm adding a screen in Here we go app. I need a similar implementation in my application also.

[image: Here we go app implementation]

Answer (score 0):

The process is to traverse a tree of `MapPackage`.

- You start from the root MapPackage
- Scan for the title returned by `getTitle()` or the english title returned by `getEnglishTitle()`
- As necessary, repeat this operation through the children returned by `getChildren()` until you find the MapPackage you are looking for.
- Once you found the MapPackage of interest, get its unique identifier with `getId()`
- A list of such identifiers is what `installMapPackages(List<Integer>)` eats

I am not aware of a more straightforward way that will lookup the tree for you.

*Couple references:*

- [Map Package Download](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/maps-offline-maploader.html)
- [Class MapPackage](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/odml/MapPackage.html)